# EJB lookup failed

Tags: java, rest, ejb

Am trying to lookup an EJB and when am doing so, getting error as
`While trying to look up comp/env/ejb/UserImpl in /app/webapp/BSWeb/131433158`

RestImpl:
`

```
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("UserSession")
@Stateless 
public class UserSessionManagerImpl {
@Context
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
@Context
HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse;
@POST
@Path("retrieveUserProfile")
public RetrieveUserProfile retrieveUserProfile (RetrieveUserProfileRequest request)
{
try {
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
IUserSessionManagerIntf manager = (IUserSessionManagerIntf) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/UserSessionImpl");
replyVO.retrieveUserProfile();
} catch (Exception namingException) {
namingException.printStackTrace();
}
```

My EJB

```
@Stateless(name = "UserSessionImpl", mappedName = "ejb/UserSessionImpl")
@Local
public class UserSessionImpl implements IUserSessionManagerIntf {
retrieveUserProfile(){
....
}
```

Can some one help on this. Am using this in a rest implementation. On ejb lookup it fails

Comment: Which application server are you using? They typically print the deployed EJB jndi names. Also, it should be possible to browse them through some administration console.

Comment: Oracle Weblogic 10.3.6 server and my EJB is configured like this. <module><java>lib/SecurityDataServices.jar</java></module>.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put:

`@EJB(name="ejb/UserSessionImpl", beanInterface = IUserSessionManagerIntf.class)`

on your `UserSessionManagerImpl` class?
`mappedName` property is vendor specific. You should not assume that you'll find your bean with mapped name under `java:comp/env`. Instead you can use my above suggestion or global JNDI names (or vendor-specific functionality - check in docs).

Comment: I didn't use @EJB, i have used @Stateless(name = "UserSessionImpl", mappedName = "ejb/UserSessionImpl") in UserSessionManagerImpl class (Bean class).

Comment: From the code you provided I see you use `@Stateless(name = "UserSessionImpl", mappedName = "ejb/UserSessionImpl")` in `UserSessionImpl`, not in `UserSessionManagerImpl`. The intention of using `@EJB` in `UserSessionManagerImpl` is to establish a reference to your bean.

Comment: Sorry it is in UserSessionImpl. I could resolve this issue once i keep the EJB module in EAR directory where my web module is present(outside lib directory).  But in my application we have all the java and EJB modules packaged in EAR lib folder. So how can i access the EJB from web module(outside lib) to EJB located in lib folder. is there any way of denoting to look bean inside my lib directory?

Comment: Why don't you use my above suggestion?